Android Automotive - I am trying to achieve radio buttons kind of UI through Images, but couldn't able to make it
Actually I am trying to achieve radiobutton kind of UI through Images in Android automative application,
I have searched various links but I couldn't able to find links related to radio buttons in Android automotive, so I am trying to achieve through Images.
Below is my Android Auto class,
import androidx.car.app.CarContext
import androidx.car.app.CarToast
import androidx.car.app.Screen
import androidx.car.app.model.Action
import androidx.car.app.model.CarIcon
import androidx.car.app.model.ItemList
import androidx.car.app.model.ListTemplate
import androidx.car.app.model.OnClickListener
import androidx.car.app.model.Row
import androidx.car.app.model.Template
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
import com.gma.ddainfotainmentsaudi.R
import com.gma.ddainfotainmentsaudi.common.TemplateUtility.createGenericAction
import com.gma.ddainfotainmentsaudi.common.TemplateUtility.createGenericActionStrip
import com.gma.ddainfotainmentsaudi.common.TemplateUtility.getIconByResource
import com.gma.ddainfotainmentsaudi.templates.AboutUsUITemplate
import com.gma.ddainfotainmentsaudi.templates.OptionsUITemplate2

class RadioCheckUITemplate3(private val carContext: CarContext) : Screen(carContext), DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private var selectedPosition = -1 // Class-level variable to store the selected position
         
    private val rows: MutableList<Row> by lazy {
        val options = arrayOf("Signals", "Alerts", "Voice")
        options.indices.map { createRow(options[it], it) }.toMutableList()
    }

    private var itemList = createItemList()

    private fun createRow(title: String, position: Int): Row {
        val isSelected = (position == selectedPosition)
        val iconRes = if (isSelected) R.drawable.selected_radiobtn else R.drawable.default_radionbtn
        return Row.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setImage(getIconByResource(iconRes, carContext),Row.IMAGE_TYPE_ICON)
            .setOnClickListener {
                val previousSelected = selectedPosition
                selectedPosition = position
                if (previousSelected != -1) {
                    updateRowImage(previousSelected, R.drawable.default_radionbtn)
                }
                updateRowImage(selectedPosition, R.drawable.selected_radiobtn)
                itemList = createItemList() // Recreate itemList after updating rows
                invalidate()
            }
            .build()
    }


    private fun updateRowImage(position: Int, iconRes: Int) {
        if (position in rows.indices) {
            val newIcon = getIconByResource(iconRes, carContext)
            val updatedRow = rows[position].title?.let {
                Row.Builder()
                    .setTitle(it)
                    .setImage(newIcon, Row.IMAGE_TYPE_ICON)
                    .setOnClickListener {
                        CarToast.makeText(
                            carContext,
                            "Selected: $it",
                            CarToast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    .build()
            }
            if (updatedRow != null) {rows[position] = updatedRow
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createItemList(): ItemList {
        val itemListBuilder = ItemList.Builder()
        rows.forEach { itemListBuilder.addItem(it) }
        return itemListBuilder.build()
    }

    private val callAction = createGenericAction(
        title = "About",
        icon = getIconByResource(
            icon = R.drawable.ic_info,
            carContext = carContext
        ),
        onClickListener = OnClickListener {
            screenManager.push(AboutUsUITemplate(carContext))
        }
    )

    private val title: String = "Settings"

    private fun createListTemplate(): ListTemplate {
        return ListTemplate.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setActionStrip(createGenericActionStrip(callAction))
            .setSingleList(itemList)
            .build()
    }

    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
        return createListTemplate()
    }

    private fun getIconByResource(resourceId: Int, carContext: CarContext): CarIcon {
        val iconCompat = IconCompat.createWithResource(carContext, resourceId)
        return CarIcon.Builder(iconCompat).build()
    }
}

Please find the image which I have achieved as UI,

By using above class, Image(default_radionbtn) is not replacing with Image(selected_radiobtn) after clicking on the selected position,I have tried in different ways but could not able to update the Image(selected_radiobtn) after clicking the position.
Could anyone please help me on this. thanks in advance.
